# How do we apply Addition Compiler Arguments to the Unity Player? Unity memory leaks debugging

Tags: unity-game-engine, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, profiling, unity-editor

I have thousands of memory leak errors (which is annoying as I've not started work yet, just installed the Top Down Engine and new Unity Input System). The errors are both in the play mode and editor mode, so it's perhaps some code that is set to [ExecuteAlways] or something similar.

As a clue, the memory profiler shows a massive spike in the "GC Allocated In Frame" sample on some frames but I don't know how to find out which objects the garbage collector is freaking out about or how to drill deeper.

These errors are all saying the following:

```
Allocation of 16 bytes at 0000013860724900

TLS Allocator ALLOC_TEMP_TLS, underlying allocator ALLOC_TEMP_MAIN has unfreed allocations, size 496

Internal: Stack allocator ALLOC_TEMP_MAIN has unfreed allocations, size 496

To Debug, run app with -diag-temp-memory-leak-validation cmd line argument. This will output the callstacks of the leaked allocations.
```

***My issue is that the last warning is not working.*** If I find the "Project Settings/Player/Addition Compiler Arguments" option and add in "-diag-temp-memory-leak-validation" (or "diag-temp-memory-leak-validation" or "/diag-temp-memory-leak-validation") then the console prints

```
error CS2007: Unrecognized option: '-diag-temp-memory-leak-validation'
```

And if I drop the '-', then I get this instead:

```
error CS2001: Source file 'D:\GameDev\UnityProjects\MyGame\diag-temp-memory-leak-validation' could not be found.
```

Can anyone help be figure out the debugging process, or just how to follow the advice on how to use the -diag-temp-memory-leak-validation flag, because the diagnostics Unity provides are not as helpful as I'm sure they were intended to be!

best
~Greg

Comment: Usually deep profile option is enough to find the peace of code that causes allocation. However, it can be buggy with low-end mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Set those Checkboxes and restart unity:

[image]

How to enable -diag-job-temp-memory-leak-validation cmd line argument